# How do I capture and resume global errors in javascript?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I am writing a testing suite for javascript and need a way to capture any JS errors and continue processing the rest of the page.

I can't use window.onerror since return true stops the browser from proceeding.  I tried using a try {} catch block but the function is run in a window setTimeout() for various reasons and that seems to mess up the try catch block.

For example, I do something like this:

```
 function test(msg, fn) {
    $('#output').text(msg);
    try {
       fn.apply(this);
    } catch(e) {
       document.write('error'+e);
    };
}
```

and then call it like this

```
 test('trying this', function() { setTimeout('afunction()',100); });
```

but if afunction() fails the error is not being caught.

Does anyone have any idea on a solution or global error handler that allows me to resume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `window.onerror`, which you can attach a handler function to. If that function returns `true`, the error is suppressed: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/qAv9J/2/.

```
window.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    return true;
};
```

Comment: Does this capture all errors? I remember something similiar for PHP which wasn't catching critical errors. - This may be simple JS, but I didn't know it. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Smamatti: I believe it does not catch syntax errors, simply because the interpreter cannot parse the `onerror` assignment if there is one.

Comment: @pimvdb this doesn't work in the case of **callbacks** such as those received from an Ajax call and is therefore not appropriate for all global errors.

Comment: @JoshL: Are you sure? It seems to work in an ajax callback as well: http://jsfiddle.net/sfA5M/2/.